# tornado websockets ioloop exception

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm trying to get the hello-world example from the tornado websockets docs working. I'm pretty new to tornado, and totally new to websockets. I have specified the following handler, straight from the docs:

```
class EchoWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print "WebSocket opened"

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(u"You said: " + message)

    def on_close(self):
        print "WebSocket closed"
```

and call it from javascript using

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6665/websocket");
ws.onopen = function() {
   ws.send("Hello, world");
};
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
   alert(evt.data);
};
```

also straight from the docs. I immediately hit three exceptions:

```
[E 111123 17:45:54 iostream:233] Uncaught exception, closing connection.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 230, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 353, in _on_headers
        self.request_callback(self._request)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1182, in __call__
        handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
    TypeError: default __new__ takes no parameters
[E 111123 17:45:54 iostream:221] Uncaught exception, closing connection.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 199, in _handle_events
        self._handle_read()
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 258, in _handle_read
        if self._read_from_buffer():
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 325, in _read_from_buffer
        self._consume(loc + delimiter_len))
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 230, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 353, in _on_headers
        self.request_callback(self._request)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1182, in __call__
        handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
    TypeError: default __new__ takes no parameters
[E 111123 17:45:54 ioloop:281] Exception in I/O handler for fd 4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 269, in start
        self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 199, in _handle_events
        self._handle_read()
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 258, in _handle_read
        if self._read_from_buffer():
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 325, in _read_from_buffer
              self._consume(loc + delimiter_len))
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 230, in _run_callback
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 173, in wrapped
        callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 353, in _on_headers
        self.request_callback(self._request)
      File "/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1182, in __call__
        handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
    TypeError: default __new__ takes no parameters
```

which I confess to being unable to properly parse, and I'm nervous to dip into tornado.web. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I'm using tornado 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have to do with the old version of Python you are using (2.5 from the logs).
The behavior of `object.__init__` and `object.__new__` changed few years ago: http://svn.python.org/view?revision=54539&view=revision

Moreover, I believe there is a typo in your question: you meant "tornado 2.1.1" not "tornado 1.2.1", right?

Comment: =) Oh the joy of using legacy systems. I think you're right, in that I'm royally messed up by both the old version of Python I'm trying to use and the old version of tornado I'm trying to use. I had kind of hoped I could just keep my eyes closed and it would all just sort itself out. Thanks for the reality check!